# building hdf5 with multiprocessing support and use it in python virtual environment

Tags: python, parallel-processing, hdf5, h5py

libhdf5-1.10-dev is installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 system via package manager and I am using virtual environments for python with the h5py binding.

How can I get hdf5 parallel to work in this situation?

I read that I have to build the lib from source with the respective multiprocessing support. But how does this effect then the virtual environment if it does?

I am confused, does somebody care to shed some light please?

Comment: I can not help you with this particular issue, but if it helps, I at one point faced this issue, I had to switch to `zarr`, you may check it out. It also supports h5 files for migration needs: https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#copying-migrating-data

Comment: I now zarr but dont like that it generates a bazillion of files whereas hdf5 only creates a single one

Comment: How are you writing to HDF5? h5py or pytables (tables)? h5py has built-in mpi support. Review this for details: (http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/mpi.html)

Comment: h5py only, but do I need to have libhdf5-dev installed with mpi support as well?

Comment: `h5py` uses the `mpi4py` package. However you also need to build HDF5 with the `--enable-parallel --enable-shared` options.Then, h5py has to be compiled in “MPI mode”. I haven't done this, but the docs explain the procedure.

Comment: Im still at a loss on how exactly to do this even with the docs. I have to install hdf5lib on my system globally and then h5py in MPI mode. But what if I use virtual environments?